# Flutter Material Design on iOS - system navigation over bottom button

Tags: ios, flutter, material-design

I have simple Material app where button is at bottom.
On Android it's OK on iOS system navigation bar at bottom is over this button.
What is the best solution to have button out of this navigation and still be OK on Android?

[image: screen of problem]

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/logo.svg",
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
          ),
          Text(initMessage),
          const Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/help'),
              child: const Text('Show Help'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your column widget with a SafeArea widget.

so that it becomes.

```
SafeArea {
child: Column {
```

for more please see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html